# Is it possible to make a responsive div with a background-image that maintains the ratio of the background-image like with an <img>?

Tags: css, responsive-design, background-image

Not a a native english speaker so there's probably a better way to shape the question...anyway:

What I want to create is similar to the header here: http://thegreatdiscontent.com/adam-lisagor
The header image is shown fully in all screensizes, and the aspect-ratio of the image is of course always correct. 
This is made using an  and getting the text to appear on the  using position: absolute.

But if you use css for the background-image instead of an , you'll get something like this header: http://elegantthemes.com/preview/Harmony/ 
Resize browser to see parts of the background being left out.

Is it possible to make a a div look and behave like the first link, using the background-image css property like on the second link?
Or do I have to change how my entire header works and use the  for the background for it to show fully in all screensizes?

I would like to have a header background that doesn't leavy anything out, but is fixed like this http://getflywheel.com/
Only idea so far is to make a transparent png that has the correct ratio of the image, and then use background-image that has background-attachment:fixed. But this doesn't seem very smart.

Hopefully I was clear enough that I'll get understood. Thank you all very much in advance!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is a nice and simple tip with only css/html:

**Ingredients**

- Transparent PNG image with the desired ratio
  (transparent-ratio-conserver.png)
- tag
- Different images for different view-ports (retina.jpg, desktop.jpg,
  tablet.jpg...)

The idea is to open an  tag and to assign to it a transparent image (with our desired ratio). We also add class="responsive-image" that's all in HTML.

```
<img src="img/transparent-ratio-conserver.png" class="responsive-image">
```

In the CSS, we set background-size to fit the  and we choose the width of our image.

```
.responsive-image{
    width: 100%;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

and finally, we serve for every view-port the right image:

```
/* Retina display */
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px){
    .responsive-image{
        background-image: url('../img/retina.jpg');
    }
}
/* Desktop */
@media screen and (min-width: 980px) and (max-width: 1024px){
    .responsive-image{
        background-image: url('../img/desktop.jpg');
    }
}
/* Tablet */
@media screen and (min-width: 760px) and (max-width: 980px){
    .responsive-image{
        background-image: url('../img/tablet.jpg');
    }
}
/* Mobile HD */
@media screen and (min-width: 350px) and (max-width: 760px){
    .responsive-image{
        background-image: url('../img/mobile-hd.jpg');
    }
}
/* Mobile LD */
@media screen and (max-width: 350px){
    .responsive-image{
        background-image: url('../img/mobile-ld.jpg');
    }
}
```

You can download the demo from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c9i8zhvks9vzlew/Demo.zip).

Comment: This is the way I went. But if you check out different mobile devices like (some crappy) Android Tablets, you'll notice that if the <img> has background-image, it doesn't work properly. 
So I had a <div> with background, and the div contains the transparent png to preserve the ratio in all screen sizes.

Comment: I googled many posts about this issue and none resolve my need too. Your way works except one case: my background image has different ratio between desktop/mobile screens. The ultimate problem is we can't change image source in CSS.

Answer (score 3):

This is done with the background-size property:

```
background-size: cover;
```

Cover will make the image as small as it can be, whilst still covering the entirety of its parent, and maintaining its aspect ratio.

You may also want to try `contain`, which makes the image as big as it can be whilst still fitting inside the parent.

**Source(s)**

[MDN - background-size CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-size)

Comment: But how to make the div have the right aspect ratio of the background-image on all screen sizes? I mean, won't parts of the image get left outside the screen like here http://elegantthemes.com/preview/Harmony/

Comment: It make the image as small as it can be, whilst still covering the whole parent, and keeping its aspect ratio. So if it is a different aspect ratio to the screen some clipping will occur, but it's minimal.

Answer (score 2):

I think theres a better solution than `contain` or `cover` (which dind't work for me, btw).
Here's an example I recently used for a logo:

```
#logo{
    max-width: 600px;
    min-height: 250px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: url(../images/logo.png) no-repeat center;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

So now we have a responsive div with a backgound image, which size is set to the full width of the div.

Answer (score 0):

Although there are other solutions.
% will scale the div to image size or the aspect ratio.

```
.responsive-image{
width: 100%;
background-image: url(x.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass the height to width ratio to the element.
For an image 1400x600;

*1400:600 = 98:42*

```
span( style="padding-bottom:42%;
             width:98%;
             background:url('/images/img1.jpg');
             background-size:contain;
             display:inline-block;")
```

would display the same as

```
img(src="/images/img.jpg" style="width:98%;")
```