# Make background img responsive

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a background the same height and widt as the picture which is selected in the background property. 
And I would like the heigth and width to be responsive and not static.

I know it can be done with an image, but would like it to be a background if it is possible?

```
<div style="background:url('http://cdn.lolhappens.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Aww-in-a-picture.jpg'); background-size:100%"></div>
```

A simple [fiddle here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15883157/is-it-possible-to-make-a-responsive-div-with-a-background-image-that-maintains-t)

And I would like it to have same effect as if you use an image as [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/C8wAU/)

### I solved it like this:

I found my anwser [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15883157/is-it-possible-to-make-a-responsive-div-with-a-background-image-that-maintains-t)

The fix in short, was to make a transparent picture and then have a div to that img container like this:

```
    <div style="background:url('background.jpg'); background-size:100% 100%; width:100%; height:100%">
       <img src="transparent.png" style="width:100%" />
    </div>
```

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15883157/is-it-possible-to-make-a-responsive-div-with-a-background-image-that-maintains-t

Comment: `background-size:contain` will scale the image to the largest size it can go within the div, or if you don't want any white space you can use `background-size:cover` - this will scale you image up to a size where the complete div is covered (any overflow is hidden)

Answer (score 3):

```
/* default screen, non-retina */
.hero  { background-image: url("../img/candc970.jpg"); }

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    /* Small screen, non-retina */
    .hero  { background-image: url("../img/candc290.jpg"); }
}
@media
only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (max-width: 320px) {
    /* Small screen, retina */
    .hero  { background-image: url("../img/candc290@2x.jpg"); }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 538px) {
    /* Medium screen, non-retina */
    .hero { background-image: url("../img/candc538.jpg"); }
}
@media
only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 538px) {
    /* Medium screen, retina */
    .hero  { background-image: url("../img/candc538@2x.jpg"); }
}
@media
only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (min-width: 539px) {
    /* Large screen, retina */
    .hero  { background-image: url("../img/candc970@2x.jpg"); }
}
```

you can mange with CSS

Answer (score 1):

add `background-size:100% 100%` to your style

```
div {
    background:url('http://cdn.lolhappens.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Aww-in-a-picture.jpg') no-repeat;
    width:100%; /* make sure you have set this */
    height:100%; /* make sure you have set this */
    background-size:100% 100%
}
```

[**demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ewe4V/7/)

Comment: This dosen't work. It stil dont show the image. fiddle = http://jsfiddle.net/ewe4V/1/

Comment: @AndreasBaran : thats because you have not set the `height` and `width` of the `div` ....please see the fiddle i just added :)

Comment: The problem is that I do not have any size to the div container. a fiddle here = http://jsfiddle.net/XrqBe/. But I would like not to hardcode the height 190px. I would like the effect you can do with images fiddle here = http://jsfiddle.net/C8wAU/.

Comment: @AndreasBaran : so u want to set background image without setting any height to the div??

Answer (score 0):

@media screen and (max-width: 380px) {
    .hero
    { 
        background-image: url("../img/IMGBIG.jpg"); 
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    .hero 
    { 
        background-image: url("../img/IMGSMALL.jpg"); 
    }
}